# get last div with elements among existing(static) divs using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi i am doing a flower application in which i have 1 parent div with 7 static div elements as children with their resp id like div1,div2..div6 and div_image and three buttons 'assign images' and 'add image' and 'sort images'

on 'assign images' click ,out of 14 images 12 images are added to div_image.

now there are two situations

1. before sort if 'add image' clicked , append 1 image to div_image (its working)

2.when sort clicked those 12 images from div_image get shuffled and are appended to div1,div2,div3 and div4 (each 3 images per div) and other div5,div6 remains empty.
so now when 'add image' clicked i want to append 1 image to last div(having child's) from div1-div6 in this case 'div4' (as per note it could be div2)

i have tried nth-last-child as well as parent_div:last but its not working ,i am getting div6 instead i want div4.

someone please give me any ideas?

**Note**:
here after 'sort' i am taking images from database so if 12 images then each 3 images will be appended to div1-div4 and if i am having 7 images then only 2 div means div1 and div2 will be appended with 3 images so all other from div3-div6 remains empty

i am using jquery for this functions.

Comment: Can you show the html structure with parent and all child `div` elements ?

Comment: @ himanshu                                                                                        <div id="images_parent" width="100%">
    <div id="div1" style='float:left;'>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style='float:left;'>
    </div>
    <div id="div3" style='float:left;'>
    </div>
    <div id="div4" style='float:left;'>
    </div>
    <div id="div5" style='float:left;'>
    </div>
    <div id="div6" style='float:left;'>
    </div>
    <div id="div_image">
    </div>
   </div>

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, every child div has it's own id like div1, div2, div3, div4, div5 and div6, right ? If so, you can easily access every one of them all with the following code :

```
$('#div1'), $('#div2'), $('#div3'), $('#div4'), $('#div5'), $('#div6')
```

If you however don't have any specific id for those divs, then you should at least add them a class 'child' so you can do something like this

```
$('.child:nth-child(4)')
```

Think about adding also some identifier for the parent, so you can make your work easier.

EDIT after author's edit:

Now, seeing the further requirements and the provided code structure, here is 1 selector which will return you the last div that has anything inside :

```
$('#images_parent div[id^=div]').not('div[id$="_image"],div:empty').last();
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer  but please check i have edited question to know more about my question. though i am having id to all div but after sort how do i get div with child elements out of 6 , it can be div3 or div4 .

Comment: after sort how would i get that out of 7 divs 3 are having child elements and left 4 are empty ????

Comment: I have edited my code, please take a look at the last line.